# Can "invaild flags" flag be ever marked helpful?

Tags: support, flagging, 10k-tools

I got entries like that a lot:

> invalid flags – Mołot X mins ago   disputed - flags should not be used to indicate technical inaccuracies, or an altogether wrong answer

I can't recall it ever be marked any other way. Is it a coincidence, or the way system is designed?

Comment: Mołot, if it is any comfort, I started to get those as well a couple of weeks back. I think the implied message is that the diamond mods don't want wrong answers flagged for removal. I.e. flagging is reserved for outright spam and "not an answer" (such as "Thanks!" and "I have this problem too") "answers".  So I've cut down on my flagging as a result.  Hopefully, the diamond mods can step in here a make it clear what the recommended practice is.

Comment: @GisleHannemyr but I got that comment on my "invalid flags" flag - when I **agreed** with mod. Or, chronologically, mod agreed with me.

Comment: Can you give an example post or two that these were on?

Comment: @MPD http://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/105457/16495 was marked NAA if I remember correctly. I disagreed, marked as "it has invalid flags", and got exactly the result I posted in this question - "disputed".

Comment: @MPD but if you can browse my flag history, most if not all "invalid flags" marks I raised was marked that way, no matter if I was right or wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It simply means you marked a flag as invalid, and marking a flag as invalid is shown as disputed, since it doesn't increase the number of helpful flags, but it doesn't increase the number of the declined flags either. That is how the system works.

The moderator message you see is not for your flag, but for the flag you marked as invalid. in fact, the timeline I see is the following.

> [image: screenshot]

Somebody flagged the answer as not an answer, you marked the flag as invalid, and a moderator declined it.